# Using "Acts of God" in legal term

Tags: terminology, history, legalese

I wonder why on a lot of legal term in English country using "Acts of God" as an events outside human control?

As an Indonesian, I think everything that happens in this world is an act of God. And it reminds me one of The Simpsons episode "[Sky Police](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3181538/)" which Chief Wiggum crash to a church and the insurance companies won't cover it because Reverend Lovejoy said it's an "acts of God."

Why not use the term "natural disaster"? In Indonesia, if you say it's a natural disaster, the company cannot be blamed for a mistake they've made, like "[Lumpur Sidoarjo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidoarjo_mud_flow)."

Comment: Legal language is extremely slow to change, as it must be far more specific than ordinary communication— and it is safer to use funny-sounding constructions with medieval origins whose legal implications are well-established than to craft a modernized but potentially ambiguous new version. The simplest employment contract might include clauses releasing a party from claims "from the beginning of time," or claiming other rights "throughout the universe, in perpetuity." Something being an act of God has nothing to do with God; it is a set phrase that has been used for many decades.

Comment: I realize I misunderstood your question when I posted my initial answer. I may delete it. But I think you've answered your own question: these things are called "acts of God" because they're *not* "acts of man". No man controls them or could control them, so if you want to assign agency for some specific event (and human nature is strongly inclined to do so for major events, especially major tragic events), you must assign it somewhere else: to God, who, by the definition of that word, is the ultimate agent for everything.

Comment: @choster Please use your comment as an answer. I am afraid starting a religious debate with someone.

Comment: The legal term "act of God" is of long standing and is fairly well established (though it's possible it's been supplanted by another term in some US states).  Precisely what it means, though, is probably more the province of "case law" than legislative or theological reasoning.  It basically means something that was beyond the control of the parties involved, usually (but likely not always) of natural origin (weather, earthquake, etc).

Comment: Good to know that you'd consider my unilateral nuking of this question an act of God. Good to know.

Comment: Just as a point of interest, there is also the similar legal term "act of war", which means roughly what it sounds like.  There was much discussion of this point following the September 11th attacks on the World Trade Center, as "act of war" clauses were present in several insurance policies involved, and they potentially relieved insurance carriers of any responsibility to pay for the damages.  (I don't recall how it all came out -- mostly argued to death in court, I suspect.)

Comment: @PhilLello - It is a legitimate concept/practice.  When you buy insurance you agree to a contract.  If the contract includes an "act of God" exclusion then presumably you're getting a lower rate as a result.

Comment: @HotLicks It was meant somewhat humorously - although only somewhat based on my experiences of stalling tactics to avoid payment. Insurace is certainly an area where _caveat emptor_ applies.

Comment: @PhilLello - Certainly insurance salesmen stand somewhere near politicians on the low-life scale.  An enormous amount of the insurance sold in the US is essentially useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quote [choster's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/314980/44001/#comment714448_314980):

> Legal language is extremely slow to change, as it must be far more specific than ordinary communication— and it is safer to use funny-sounding constructions with medieval origins whose legal implications are well-established than to craft a modernized but potentially ambiguous new version.
>
> The simplest employment contract might include clauses releasing a party from claims "from the beginning of time," or claiming other rights "throughout the universe, in perpetuity."
>
> Something being an act of God has nothing to do with God; it is a set phrase that has been used for many decades.

I think it's more enlighten and answer my question, "Why not use the term 'natural disaster'?"

Comment: By the way, there's a term in Indonesian, "hal-hal yang berada di luar kekuasaan kami" literally "the things that are beyond our control." I think It more has a clearer and neutral meaning than "Act of God."

Answer (score 10):

"Act of God" is a legal definition:

> ***An act of God is a legal term*** for events outside human control, such as sudden natural disasters, for which no one can be held responsible.

Probably its origin as a legal expression is because it is closely related to natural disaster, that is something that is beyond human control:

> The phrase “act of God” is sometimes used to attribute an event to divine intervention. Often it is used in conjunction with a natural disaster or tragic event.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_God)

According to online Etymology Dictionary :

> " Act of God "uncontrollable natural force" recorded by 1726.

Comment: You mean the origin of the legal usage?

Comment: Ok, the reason why it is used also as a legal expression.

Comment: @Dan Well, then you have to define "natural" and "disaster"

Answer (score 1):

Act of God is describing naturally occuring events over which we humans could not predict, or predict its severity. 
Eg, an IT company's building housing hundreds of servers used by the public gets struck by lightening and gets taken offline. The public users depending on the up keep of servers for their business my loose some income while they work to get the servers running again. But getting struck by lightening was an 'act of God'. **Random event happening such as a lightening strike, which is not really a 'natural disaster' on a big scale, but locally to that one building whose servers went offline, would be Act of God.**
However if someone working at the company maliciously causes data loses then its different.

Also, you say *"As Indonesian, I think everything happen in this world is acts of God"* but it can't be everything, eg. it was you, who came online and wrote the question, it wasn't God doing it...Legally or Spiritually you have to take responsibility for your actions.

Comment: Yes, and no. If God will I can had stomach ache which prevent me to do so. But like my initial question why not use term "Natural Disaster"?

Comment: Remember [Sky Police](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3181538/)? Someone can exploit this term for their benefit.

Comment: By saying Act of God people are covering all bases against legal action whereby they could not foresee a random event happening such as a lightening strike, which is not really a 'natural disaster' on a big scale, but locally to that one building whose servers went offline.......(If you got stomach ache then, it could be a number of reasons why, eg. may have been something *you* ate....Hardly Gods' fault.

Comment: I think a lot of folks (in and out of the legal profession) would argue that having a server taken down by a bolt of lightning was not an "act of God", but a lack of adequate preparation/protection on the part of the service provider.  While an individual lightning strike is unpredictable, it is quite predictable that there will be lightning strikes from time to time, and ordinary prudence would suggest taking reasonable precautions against such a possibility.

Comment: No, it could happen outside to the incoming power source, like the overhead cables etc. Outside transformer catching fire from lightening strike and then there is power outage. etc.....

Comment: @rkchl - And why was there not an adequate backup power supply??

Comment: In English law, taking Wikipedia as my guide, it would be a matter of whether the event "is not realistically possible to guard against". So if the building has a lightning conductor and redundant power supply and all that stuff, and yet *nevertheless* a direct lightning strike somehow takes out the servers, then I suppose you could claim an Act of God since the usual realistic precautions were insufficient.

Comment: Then again, the other side might want to argue that the servers being taken out is in itself strong evidence that the usual realistic precautions were *not* properly followed, given that buildings are struck by lightning all the time. Anyway I think the point stands, even if the example isn't clear as to why this lightning strike was unusual, that "Act of God" can include things that wouldn't necessarily be understood to be "natural disasters" in the language of contracts. Fairly disastrous for this company, sure.

Comment: By the way, there's a term in Indonesian, "hal-hal yang berada di luar kekuasaan kami" literally "the things that are beyond our control." I think It more has a clearer and neutral meaning than "Act of God."

Comment: You people lol.....come on, the lightening was meant to be an example, we're not talking about an official court case here, but trying to highlight a case where its not a 'natural disaster' covering a large area, but local to one building........And the lightening could have started a small fire, damaging any redundant power supply etc.